# Ricci flow and conformal classes

Tags: conformal-geometry, ricci-flow

Is it true that the conformal class of the metric is preserved under Ricci flow? Is there an easy argument?

Answer (score 2):

It is only always true in dimension 2. In this case it is easily seen as the Ricci flow equation reduces to
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g(t) = -R_{g(t)}g(t)
$$
for $R_{g(t)}$ the scalar curvature function for the metric at time $t$. Then by uniqueness of the solution if it exists, the metric at time $t$ is given at some point $x$ by
$$
g(t) = e^{-\int_0^tR_{g(s)}(x)ds}g(0).
$$
I'm not sure how to construct a counter-example in higher dimension but for non-Einstein initial metrics I don't see a reason why the flow would preserve the conformal class of the metric.

Comment: Also not a concrete counter-example, but an argument which makes your last point plausible:
The Weyl curvature is invariant under conformal variation. Now take any 2-positive curvature operator with non-zero Weyl curvature. By Böhm-Wilking 2008 the (normalized) Ricci flow will evolve it into a multiple of the identity, i.e. with Weyl curvature zero. So the metric has to leave the starting conformal class.